# How can I capture keys on a WinForms application when the application is in focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I capture keys on a WinForms application when the application is in focus?

I have tried using the `Form_KeyDown` and `Form_KeyUp` events but they don't work the way I want them to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `KeyPreview` to true

Here's a sample `OnKeyDown` override for your form that eats the keystroke and prevents it from being propagated to other events:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // do this to 'eat' the keystroke
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: By eating you mean, it doesn't get propagated to other events, right?

Comment: Yes, it will not pass it along to any other events.